# How to licence out photos to postcard or gift suppliers

Tags: landscape, business, licensing

I am a London-based photographer and I focus on landscape & building photography. So being based in London that means I tend to focus on many of the cities landmarks and tourist attractions.

I would like to licence out my photos as I think they suit the gift/postcard market. Does anyone know of companies in the UK that deal with and licence photos from photographers?

I don't want to go down the stock photography route because they are over saturated.

Comment: Have you contacted any of the companies making postcards to ask where they get photos? I would just go into a shop, look for a few different company names on postcards, then look them up online.

Comment: I did think of that but and even tried looking up postcard suppliers but many of the main sites seem to be produce your own postcard sites.

Comment: I think you'll be unlucky on this one, mass produced cards seem to use only the most generic 'stock' photos available to try to avoid offending as many people as possible. The companies that produce these cards are unlikely to be interested in your efforts when they can already have 'stock shot no 27' that they paid £50 for and have been using for the last twenty years.

Comment: Yeah that was what I thought regarding their stock photography options. It may be worth trying though because my Photos tend to look stock based :). London landmarks, buses etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked in [Writers' & Artists' Yearbook](http://www.writersandartists.co.uk/) to see if the companies are listed. This book will give you pretty up-to-date information on who is publishing what and the submission guidelines are and (occasionally) prices they are willing to pay.

Also have you looked in to approaching local tourist attractions, charities and even businesses to see if they would be interested in using your work in a more localised campaign?

Print companies like Vistaprint and Moo have reasonable prices on small print runs of post cards and you can sell them at local outlets, markets etc.

Once you have a track records you may have better luck approaching the larger companies directly.